# inequality for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

In general, from triangle inequality we have, for $|z_1+\epsilon~  z_2| < 1$ and $|\epsilon|=1$,
$|z_1+\epsilon~  z_2|\leq|z_1|+|\epsilon~| | z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|$. But we can not guarantee that $|z_1|+|z_2|$ will necessarily be less than 1.

Following statement gives some general statement in this regard.

Prove that if $|z_1+\epsilon~  z_2| < 1$ , for all $|\epsilon|=1$, then $|z_1|+|z_2| < 1$ , where $z_1,z_2$ are complex numbers.

I am thinking about its analytic proof. Can any one help me ?

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have done.

Comment: The given statement is true for all $\epsilon$ . You are concluding from a particular value of $\epsilon$. We want the result to  be true for a suitably chosen $\epsilon$. Please think once again.

Comment: The tone you use when talking to someone trying to help with what looks to be your homework could probably use some work.

Comment: He's saying that if $z_1, z_2$ are complex numbers such that the first inequality holds for all $|\epsilon| = 1$, then the second inequality holds. Your two don't satisfy the first inequality for all suitable $\epsilon$, which is assumed.

Comment: we may use the proof of contradiction.

Comment: The added part where OP has shown an approach (which didn't get to a proof) shows a good effort, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z_1=\rho_1e^{it_1}$ and $z_2=\rho_2e^{it_2}$, and put $\epsilon=e^{it}.$
Now choose $t$ so that $t_1 \equiv t_2+t$ mod $2\pi$, and arrive at

$$z_1+\epsilon z_2=(\rho_1+\rho_2)e^{it_1}.$$ This number has norm $\rho_1+\rho_2$ and this norm is assumed less than $1$, so the proof is immediate, since you want to conclude $\rho_1+\rho_2<1$ in the notation used here.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $\varepsilon$ is a complex number with $|\varepsilon|=1$, then the mapping $z\mapsto \varepsilon z$ is a *rotation* (by the angle $\arg(\varepsilon)$ that the $0$-->$\varepsilon$ vector encloses with the right axis of real line). So, you can make $\ \varepsilon \,z_2\ $ *parallel* to $z_1$...

Answer (score 1):

Assume on the contrary that $|z_1|+|z_2| \ge 1$, in particular $|z_1|+|z_2| \geq 1$.

Consider $z_1$ and $\epsilon z_2$, there exists a $\epsilon$ such that $\arg(z_1)=\arg(\epsilon z_2)$.

Then for this case, $|z_1+\epsilon z_2|=|z_1|+|\epsilon z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|\geq 1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Nothing has been told about the contradictory case when $|z_1|+|z_2|>1$.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer, it should also be true for $\ge 1$